# Where is the right place to put Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true) in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got this error

> com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Modifications to Config objects
>   must occur before they are in use

when I include

> Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true)

in my launcher activity onCreate() method.

Where is the right place to put the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often initially put the lines in my main activity. When I get that error, it's a good time to move it to a better place. :-)

A good place to put this would be in the Application subclass:

```
public class DemoApplication extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you! For providing more information for beginner like me, can refer to https://www.mobomo.com/2011/05/how-to-use-application-object-of-android/ on how to add application object.

Comment: Thank you Frank van Puffelen. How did you figure this out, I can't find this info in any documentation.

Comment: My app crashes if I don't place the line for Firebase.setAndroidContext(this) in each activity individually. Doing it in application is insufficient.

Comment: Nevermind, I see in the documentation that it should be fine. My app actually has a bug where initialization fails. My apologies. https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/setup.html